# Unable to set up SVN on a CentOS server

Tags: apache, svn, centos

I am trying to set up an SVN server on a Linux server, but I am facing the issue in setting up the server:

Below is the configuration I did:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/subver/public_html/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I try to checkout from my local machine I am getting this error:

> Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http:///svn'

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for Server Fault. http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

**Never** place repositories *physically* under ordinary web-root - it's extremely bad and insecure and error-full idea

`SVNParentPath /home/subver/public_html/svn` + `<Location /svn>` is your problem. If public_html is web-root of "just Apache" (and it seems so) you have **real subdirectory `/svn`**, which you try to redefine with **"virtual" Location** under the same path and get permanent redirect between these two locations: real and virtual, as expected by any good Apache-admin

Move repositories outside web-space (YOU MUST DO IT), change `SVNParentPath` accordingly to new location.

Lame and lazy solution, source of future big headache - use another path, than `/svn`, for Location container